# Pre-processing emails sent with external client through AWS SES SMTP

Tags: node.js, smtp, tls1.2, amazon-ses

I have several external email clients configured to send from alias (my domain) address through **SES** *SMTP* using *TLS*. I'd like to catch emails to modify and then to send to destinations.

As i can guess, the straight approach is to launch a public *AWS* instance capable of *TLS* connection + *SMTP* receiving, doing my job and sending with **SES** API. Taking such emails are sent only by my colleagues from remote locations, credentials+*TLS* are enough, and AWS **SES** will provide with DKIM/DMARC. So I need to implement the first two steps the simplest way.

Please advice me a robust *Linux* software for this task. Or the most primitive, but reliable *node.js* library(-ies). Or, maybe, another solution?

Thank you in advance, this is not "save me a cent" case, indeed. I just need to add some automation to manually sent emails.

Comment: If I understood correctly, external email clients are currently sending directly via SES using your verified domain, in this case you can't modify anything, even if you set a instance with email receiving capability, are you going to configure them all to relay to your server instead of SES ? If this is feasible, you would want to create a web page instead and have them make HTTP(S) POST to your server with from, to,subject,body,attachment etc and use PHP mailer to modify and send them via SES.

Comment: @JamesDean Thank you for your response. Your assumption is right. But my colleagues want to keep using their email clients, so I need to setup SMTP to SES API relay on an AWS instance. Kinda MTA SMTP receive module over TLS/SSL on ports 587/465. When they send email, my relay is to 1) establish TLS or SSL secure connection, 2) handshake and authorize client with SMTP to retrieve all email content & 3) send modified email from my instance to SES with API as if I am sending, not forwarding it. So, https won't help, the task requires SMTP and TLS/SSL (without DKIM etc, let Amazon care).

Comment: @JamesDean I am sure I can build such a relay myself if I find suitable node libraries or well-structured and commented MTA. But, you now, browsing GitHub can take a week...